# Radio button onclick event in reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to reproduce a sliding effect in ReactJS. I have a radio button in HTML and when I click the radio button it slides the next form. My code contains two form, LOGIN and REGISTER. Below is the preview of what I've:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SignInForm from "./SignInForm";
import SignUpForm from "./SignUpForm";

function Log() {
  const [registerForm, setRegisterForm] = useState(false);
  const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState(true);

  const handleForm = (e) => {
    const loginForm = document.querySelector("form.login");
    const loginText = document.querySelector(".title-text .login");
    const registerLink = document.querySelector(".signup-link a");

    if (e.target.id === "register") {
      setRegisterForm(true);
      setLoginForm(false)
      console.log("work");
      // loginForm.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
      // loginText.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
    } else if (e.target.id === "login") {
      setLoginForm(true);
      loginForm.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      loginText.style.marginLeft = "0%";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <div className="slide-controls">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="login" checked />
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="register" />
        <label
          for="login"
          onClick={handleForm}
          className="slide login"
        >
          Login
        </label>
        <label
          for="register"
          onClick={handleForm}
          className="slide register"
        >
          Register
        </label>
        <div className="slide-tab"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-inner">
        {loginForm && <SignInForm />}
        {registerForm && <SignUpForm />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Log;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login | Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title-text">
        <div class="title login">Login Form</div>
        <div class="title login">Sign up Form</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-container">
        <div class="slide-controls">
          <input type="radio" name="slider" id="login" checked />
          <input type="radio" name="slider" id="register" />
          <label for="login" class="slide login">Login</label>
          <label for="register" class="slide register">Register</label>
          <div class="slide-tab"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inner">
          <form action="#" class="login">
            <div class="field">
              <input
                type="email"
                name=""
                placeholder="Email Address"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" required />
            </div>
            <div class="pass-link">
              <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
            <div class="signup-link">
              Not a member?
              <a href="#">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </form>
          <form action="#" class="register">
            <div class="field">
              <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" required />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input
                type="email"
                name=""
                placeholder="Email Address"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" required />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input
                type="password"
                name=""
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="terms">
              <input type="checkbox" /> i agree and accept the
              <a href=""> terms and conditions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const loginForm = document.querySelector("form.login");
      // const registerForm = document.querySelector("form.register");
      const loginBtn = document.querySelector("label.login");
      const registerBtn = document.querySelector("label.register");
      const registerLink = document.querySelector(".signup-link a");
      // const registerText = document.querySelector(".title-text .register");
      const loginText = document.querySelector(".title-text .login");

      registerBtn.onclick = () => {
        loginForm.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
        loginText.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
      };
      loginBtn.onclick = () => {
        loginForm.style.marginLeft = "0%";
        loginText.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      };
      registerLink.onclick = () => {
        registerBtn.click();
        return false;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am used with react functional component. I want to reproduce the JavaScript code I have in my HTML so that when i click on the radio button corresponding to register, it shows the form register. By default, the Login is the form displaying on the screen. This is what i am doing :[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZMQN.png)

Comment: You have to rely on `onchange` and not on `click` for radio, checkbox. Bind an `onChange` event to your `radio` and set the right state. As in for `onchange` of login, see if it is checkd and `setLogin(true); setRegister(false);` and vice versa for the register too.

Comment: ok but here i am clicking on the label that refer to the input. and i'am even trying to console.log("Hello"), but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working over and over for many hours on the error, and finally i got a solution to my problem!!!
I used "defaultChecked" for both the radio button.
below is the code :

```js
const [registerForm, setRegisterForm] = useState(props.register);
  const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState(props.login);

  const handleForm = (e) => {
    // const registerBtn = document.querySelector("label.register");
    // const loginBtn = document.querySelector("label.login");

    const signInForm = document.querySelector("form.login");
    const signInText = document.querySelector(".title-text .login");

    if (e.target.id === "register") {
      setRegisterForm(true);     
      signInForm.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
      signInText.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
      // setLoginForm(false);
    } 
    if(e.target.id === "login") {
      setLoginForm(true);   
      signInForm.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      signInText.style.marginLeft = "0%";
      // setRegisterForm(false);   
    }
  };
```

```html
<div className="slide-controls">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="slider"
          id="login"
          defaultChecked={loginForm}
          onChange={handleForm}
        />
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="slider"
          id="register"
          defaultChecked={registerForm}
          onChange={handleForm}
        />
        <label htmlFor="login" className="slide login">
          Login
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="register" className="slide register">
          Register
        </label>
        <div className="slide-tab"></div>
      </div>
```